# Relativistic doppler effect vs Gravitational Redshift

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes, doppler-effect

I recently found a pretty unknown but remarkably clear and simple article ([Cochran, 1989](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.15816)) on different doppler shift relationships for an uniformly accelerated observer in a 1+1D flat spacetime, using the usual Rindler coordinates.

Let consider two test particles B$_{1}$ and B$_{2}$ at rest in the non-inertial reference frame of the accelerated observer. Their proper accelerations are respectively $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$, with $\alpha_{1} < \alpha_{2}$.

If B$_{1}$ sends a light signal to B$_{2}$, the doppler effect will be very simple:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f_{2}}{f_{1}} = \frac{\alpha_{2}}{\alpha_{1}} 
\end{equation}

I was interested in the analogy with the same two observers but now at rest with each others in the gravitationnal field of a black hole. B$_{1}$ is now just located above B$_{2}$, with the respective radius R$_{2}$ < R$_{1}$.

We know that their proper acceleration is:

\begin{equation}
\alpha_{i} = \frac{\frac{GM}{R^{2}_{i}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^{2}R_{i}}}} 
\end{equation}

And the Gravitational redshift can be expressed as:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f_{2}}{f_{1}} = \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^{2}R_{1}}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^{2}R_{2}}}} 
\end{equation}

Or, reformulated:

\begin{equation}
\frac{f_{2}}{f_{1}} = \frac{\alpha_{2}}{\alpha_{1}} \left( \frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}}  \right)^{2}
\end{equation}

Where does this $(R_{2}/R_{1})^{2}$ come from ?

I know that in the first case the space time is flat and in the second case it is not. I was just expecting an equivalent formula based on the equivalence principle because there are no tidal effects here.

Let me know if you have ever seen these formulas in the litterature.

Comment: What makes you think in the original example that $f_2/f_1=\alpha_2/\alpha_1$? I don't think that's even true. For example, in the limit where both alphas approach zero while remaining in some fixed ratio, the answer should be 1, not $\alpha_2/\alpha_1$. Maybe there is some context that you've omitted?

Comment: @BenCrowell have you had the opportunity to read Cochran, 1989 ? If you want I can redo the derivation of this result in the original post but it would be a copy/paste of what Cochran did

Comment: @BenCrowell To answer your question, the ratio alpha2/alpha1 is 1 at the limit alpha1 and alpha2 very small, because the fact that B1 and B2 are at rest with each others implies that alpha2 = alpha1/(1+alpha1*x0/c^2), with x0 the initial position of B2 for an inertial observer that is with B1 at an initial time.